# Reading from InflaterInputStream and parsing the result

Tags: java

I am quite new to java, just started yesterday. Since I am a big fan of learning by doing, I am making a small project with it. But I am stucked in this part. I have written a file using this function:

```
public static boolean writeZippedFile(File destFile, byte[] input) {
    try {
        // create file if doesn't exist part was here
        try (OutputStream out = new DeflaterOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destFile))) {
            out.write(input);
        }
        return true;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // error handlind was here 
    }
}
```

Now that I have successully wrote a compressed file using above method, I want to read it back to console. First I need to be able to read the decompressed content and write string representaion of that content to console. However, I have a second problem that I don't want to write characters up to first `\0` null character. Here is how I attempt to read the compressed file:

```
try (InputStream is = new InflaterInputStream(new FileInputStream(destFile))) {

}
```

and I am completely stuck here. Question is, how to discard first few character until '\0' and then write the rest of the decompressed file to console.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. The unzipped data are in the `byte[] input` right? How do you want to write them to console? As bytes? characters? Their string representation?

Comment: @c.s. First code I posted was just to show you how I have been saving the file that I now want to read. Unzipped data is not `byte[] input`. I don't have any unzipped version of the data, I am still figuring out how to read unzipped data. Second code I posted was to demonstrate my effort trying to read zipped file. I want to write them to console as string representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that your data contain text since you want to print a string respresentation. I further assume that the text contains unicode characters. If this is true, then your console should also support unicode for the characters to be displayed correctly.

So you should first read the data byte by byte until you encounter the `\0` character and then you can use a `BufferedReader` to print the rest of the data as lines of text.

```
try (InputStream is = new InflaterInputStream(new FileInputStream(destFile))) {

    // read the stream a single byte each time until we encounter '\0'
    int aByte = 0;
    while ((aByte = is.read()) != -1) {
        if (aByte == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }

    // from now on we want to print the data
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF8"));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    b.close();         

} catch(IOException e) { // handle }
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the first few characters using [InputStream#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29)

```
while (is.read() != '\0');
```